# pgp encription with public key using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pgp

I need to encrypt the files using pgp.i have dos command but i dont know how to use this command in vb.net for my windows service
Here is my pgp dos command which i need to fire using my vb.net

```
pgp --encrypt "z:\190221\bpip2\bpip2 Bicor - 232  filename.prn" --output "e:\prod\bpip2 Bicor - 232  filename.prn.pgp" --recipient CMCM-VIM
```

Comment: I think, `Process.Start` may be your friend... :-)

Comment: @muffi You are correct i can use Process.Start and even i tried to run one command as well but thing is that my file names are dynamic , so how can give filename at run time .i tried simple file copy by using Process.Start("cmd", "/c copy c:\scr\*.* c:\dst") .its working  but i need give filename during runtime ,so how can i make use filename variable?

Comment: Maybe this page will help you: https://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet

Comment: 'Required- 'pgp --encrypt "z:\190221\bpip2\bpip2 Bicor - 232  NB-022119-001.prn" --output "e:\prod\bpip2 Bicor - 232  NB-022119-001.prn.pgp" --recipient CMCM-AIA
                'PGP file and save it in z drive
                Dim cmdff As String = "pgp --encrypt " & """z:\190221\bpip2\" & fileName & """ " & "--output " & " " & """e:\prod" & fileName & ".pgp""" & " --recipient CMCM-AIA"